# Cylindrical Shell Method of finding volume around non-standard axes

Tags: integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

I am given a question to find the volume of the solid formed by a region in the second quadrant bounded above by the curve $y=-x^3$, below by the x-axis, and on the left by the line $x=-1$, revolved around the axis $x=-2$. I intend to solve this by the cylindrical shell method.

By drawing out the curve, I have come up with a few conclusions to help me set up my integral:

1. The radius of each layer of the "shell" is $x+1$, because, crudely, the interval between $x=-1$ and $x=-2$ is not bounded.
2. Height of each "shell" is given by $y=-x^3$, as given by the curve itself.
3. The region extends from $x=-1$ to $x=0$.

Hence, my integral should be $2\pi \int_{-1}^0 (x+1)(-x^3)dx$. However, it is now known to me that this is incorrect. May I know what is wrong in my thought process?

In general, is there any formula/procedure when calculating for volumes of solids formed by revolutions around non-standard axes (x and y-axes)?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cylindrical shell radius you are looking for is $(2 + x)$ and not ($1 + x)$.

As the rotation is of area between $x = -1$ and $x = 0$, around $x = -2$,

At $x = -1$, radius $ = 1$. At $x = 0$, radius $ = 2$.

So the correct integral should be -

$\displaystyle 2\pi \int_{-1}^{0} (2 + x) (-x^3) dx$

EDIT: added a diagram for the region (marked in yellow) that you are rotating around $x = -2$.

[image]

Comment: My apologies I am mildly confused. Does that mean I need to count the radius from the outer edge of the solid, and not the inner edge?

Comment: The radius varies between $1$ and $2$, correct? Can you see $(1 + x)$ does not give you the right radius? For $x = -1$, you get $0$. As the sign changes, you have to check which expresses it correctly. If it was in first quadrant, $1+x$ would have perfectly worked.

Comment: I added a diagram. I know you said you sketched but see if it helps clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see it now. It is essentially the maximum radius, minus away the range of radius as covered by $x$, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.